# SignalR and Knockout viewmodel binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, signalr

I'am trying to display product list from database using signalr and knockout.js. But without any result. Could anyone tell me what I'am doing wrong or where I have mistake? I will be very grateful for helping me.
This is the view:

```
<div class="products">
    <div class="row" data-bind="template: { name: 'productTemplate', foreach: products }">
    </div>
    <span class="messageClass" style="color: red;"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="productTemplate">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

This is the script:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            function productViewModel(id, name) {
                this.productId = id;
                this.name = ko.observable(name);
                var self = this;
            }

            function productListViewModel() {
                this.hub = $.connection.voteHub;
                this.products = ko.observableArray([]);

                var products = this.products;

                this.init = function () {
                    this.hub.server.getAllProducts();
                }

                this.hub.client.getAllProducts = function (allProducts) {
                    var mappedProducts = $.map(allProducts, function (item) {
                        return new productViewModel(item.productId, item.name)
                    });

                    products(mappedProducts);
                }
            }

            var vm = new productListViewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(vm);

            $.connection.hub.start(function () {
                vm.init();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the hub method to get all products:

```
public void GetAllProducts()
{
    VoteViewModel viewModel = new VoteViewModel();
    viewModel.Products = ProductService.GetProducts(new GetProductsRequest()).Products.ToList();

    if (viewModel.Products != null)
    {
        // TODO: pomyslec nad wysylaniem listy a nie tablicy!
        Clients.All.getAllProducts(viewModel.Products.ToArray());
    }
}
```

If I put on my hub code like this, it will work well (taken from demo app):

```
VoteViewModel vm = new VoteViewModel();
vm.Products = new List<Product>() { new Product() { Name = "Sample", Id = 1 } };
Clients.All.getAllProducts(vm.Products.ToArray());
```

My code which look like this don't work though. (i don't know why, maybe because my Product object from db, has more variables?):

```
VoteViewModel viewModel = new VoteViewModel();
viewModel.Products = ProductService.GetProducts(new GetProductsRequest()).Products.ToList();
Clients.All.getAllProducts(viewModel.Products.ToArray());
```

Here is code from my Product class: (dbcontext class)

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }

public string Description { get; set; }

[Required]
public string ImagePath { get; set; } 

public virtual ICollection<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
```

I made new ProductViewModel class which looks like this:

```
public class ProductViewModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public int VotesAmount { get; set; }
}
```

And then bind all data from db to that model, and then return List and IT WORKS NOW!, but I really don't understand why I can't just take list of products from database and send it to signalr client side (like I tried to do it before).

```
    List<ProductViewModel> prods = new List<ProductViewModel>();
    List<Product> products = ProductService.GetProducts(new GetProductsRequest()).Products.ToList();
    foreach (var item in products)
    {
        ProductViewModel prod = new ProductViewModel()
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Name = item.Name,
            Description = item.Description,
            ImagePath = item.ImagePath,
            VotesAmount = item.Votes.Count()
        };
        prods.Add(prod);
    }

    Clients.All.getAllProducts(prods.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is absolutely working fine. Please check if you have the referrence to the following files.

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.signalr-2.0.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Signalr.hubs is the main reference which gives the javascripts proxy files. If you are facing any errors please let me know.

Next thing is the property name referred in the model object creation.

```
           this.hub.client.getAllProducts = function (allProducts) {
                var mappedProducts = $.map(allProducts, function (item) {
                    return new productViewModel(item.productId, item.name)
                });

                products(mappedProducts);
            }
```

I have updated the property names to pascal case and worked for me.

```
return new productViewModel(item.ProductId, item.Name)
```

Comment: Under my javascript I have all needed references like these you have written. I fixed this names in return new productViewModel to pascal case as you advise, but even now when i'am debugging code gets to hub method, it returns arrayList with 2 product, but nothing shows on view. I tried to debugg javascript, but it's never gets into this.hub.client.getAllProducts to map products. Still i don't way that happens :( Please help

Comment: I have uploaded my demo here https://github.com/MisterFantastic/KnockoutSignalr please check the code with yours.

Comment: I edited my post above. I started to change bundles, layout.cshtml, index and when it starts work, I tried to change step by step everythink back to my code. It crashes when i changed code in hub method. I wrote everything above

Comment: can you try creating a viewmodel class containing only the id and name . Then copy the values from the original collection and pass it to the client ? Also please check the callback js method. The data may be coming in a different format you are accessing properties directly. may be its coming different !

Comment: I do like you said and it starts work (don't know why though). I extend fields in javascript and in new viewmodel class and it works properly. But question remains --> why I can't return list of products from db and bind it in script (like I tried to do it before). Why it's not working properly then.

Comment: Have you check at your client code callback method how the object is received or is it not coming there ?

Comment: If I'am sending this: Clients.All.getAllProducts(viewModel.Products.ToArray()); --->I can't get inside mapping method in client code.

Comment: @Thanigainathan If I could give you more up-votes for your help with this question I would! Great job